Unable to see my Android Emulator by clicking it on my taskbar(only visible on hover)
My command prompt after building the project.
This is while opening my project in an emulator just after creating it.
As you can see, the emulator is only visible while hovering and not even after clicking that taskbar icon of Android Emulator!!
This is totally working with Android Studio but not with Visual Studio Code.
Is there any extension like flutter-emulator for React Native Emulator in VS Code?
I've tried searching and even took help from chatgpt but whatever it said didn't worked!
So, by any chance if somebody knows the solution. Please Help!

[Guys its visible now! Thanks to ChatGPT. I've tried before but somehow got misunderstood few steps but I tried again and got successful.]https://i.sstatic.net/4Onkv8Lj.png
How I did it?
Ans -> When you run the command(npm run android/ npx expo start) the simulator opens at the end but in my case it was not visible but active. So Press ctrl+shift+esc buttons to open taskbar to see active apps list. In which there must be an android simulator running. In my case it was named different as qemu-system-... rightclick on it ---expand---android sim.---right click---maximize. That's it.
